# I'm installing Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell C521 keep getting error 8000

Tags: boot, system-installation, dell, dvd

While installing Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell C521, I keep getting error 8000 "reading sector" a few times. On a previous installation attempt I got another error number which I believe was 3820 a bunch of times with different sector numbers.

I have both a live USB and DVD in my system. When I take out the DVD it halts at the BIOS. I tested my USB on another computer and it works fine. When I put back the DVD, it gives me all the errors and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an issue with the hard disk itself. Try using the livecd, opening the disks application and checking the SMART status of the disk, and see if there are any bad sectors

Comment: I'll do that. Maybe its just my drive?

Comment: as in a bad hard drive. I know many people will say to replace it immediately, but I've had surface problems on a 320gb hard drive of mine for more than 2 years now, been using it in my primary laptop for all that time. It had been thrown around a little roughly while running, but now has a few bad areas. I just solved the problem by partitioning around them and the issue hasn't rared its head since